# How "Quick shortcut maker" and "App shortcut maker" work?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, shortcut

I found some cool apps on play store.

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut&hl=no
- com.bhanu.appshortcutmaker

These apps find every activities in my every installed apps.

When I click activity, it just run directly.

How could it possible?

Can we figure out any activities in any app?

and is it possible to run any activities by other app? even if that activity has no intent-filter in manifest file?

[Screen shot - Quick shortcut maker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfRPA.png)

and I'd appreciate it if add some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

First get all `ActivityInfo` of install activities in your device.

```
 public List<ActivityInfo> getAllRunningActivities(Context context) {
    List<ActivityInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();

    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = context.getPackageManager()
            .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getAllRunningActivities: " + applicationInfo.packageName);
        try {
            PackageInfo pi = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            Collections.addAll(result, pi.activities);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then `startActivity()` by using that info.

```
for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : getAllRunningActivities(this)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + activityInfo.toString());
        if (yourCondition && filterResult) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, activityInfo.name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can we run any activity no matter it has intent-filter or not??

Comment: Absolutely yes. Please give it a try @restforest

Comment: ActivityInfo activityInfo = getAllRunningActivities(this).get(0);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, activityInfo.name);
        startActivity(intent);